# Zebex Z-3100 USB scanner drops character

Tags: usb, barcode

When scanning an EAN-8 barcode containing the 8 digits 00032605 ubuntu incorrectly returns 0003265 while windows correctly return 00032605. The last digit 5 is a check-digit.

Are there any configuration I should know about?
Please help!

Answer (score 4):

I have exact the same model. I almost threw the scanner away because of this problem. After years, I finally found the solution. It's right on the their website: http://www.zebex.com/supportsservices/Faq_Scanning_BarcodeReading.html

> How do I correct the problem where data is outputted incorrectly only
> when the scanner is connected via USB port?
>
> When the scanner is able to read the barcode the problem may be caused
> by the incorrect host interpretation of the USB protocol. Please use
> the following barcodes to adjust the USB speeds.
>
> ．USB0: Regular speed mode. Usually for older operating systems like
> Windows 98 when default setting is not working.
>
> ．USB1: Full speed mode. The default speed of the scanner.
>
> ．USB2: Middle speed mode. Usually for Mac O.S. or Linux O.S when
> default setting is not working. [image]

I set the scanner to use USB2 mode, and it worked fine. (Damn! They should have put it the document.)

Comment: Same issue observed with Zebex Z-5160. (Indeed, "Programming Guide" dose not mention this option)

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely as it seems, I've experienced this exact problem and found a solution that works for me.

http://support.epostraders.co.uk/support-files/documents/39/3kb-Z31xx_ProgrammingGuide.pdf

Page 22, language support - change it from default USA to UK.

Hope it helps!